# Increase/customize column size in datatables excel export

Tags: php, excel, datatables, yii2

I have been trying to customize/increase the column size in excel when exporting using data tables to no avail. The data that i receive upon export is compressed in the column and one cannot view the whole details.

This the excel file that i get upon export:

[image]

How to achieve this?

```
   <?php

   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\grid\GridView;


    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $searchModel app\models\StatusSearch */
   /* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

   $this->title = 'Report For B2C Services';
   $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
   ?>


     <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"> 
 </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.6.0/jszip.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.6.0/jszip.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"> 
  </script>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="display nowrap" id="example1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DEBIT ACCOUNT</th>
        <th>SOURCE NO</th>
        <th>BENEFICIARY NO</th>
        <th>TRANSACTION DATE</th>
        <th>AMOUNT</th>
        <th>RECEIPT</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($model as $block) {?>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><?= $block['DEBITACCOUNT'];?></td>
            <td><?= $block['SOURCEMOBILENUMBER'];?></td>
            <td><?= $block['BENEFICIARYMOBILENUMBER'];?></td>
            <td><?= $block['TRN_DATE'];?></td>
            <td><?= $block['AMOUNT'];?></td>
            <td><?= $block['RECEIPT'];?></td>

        </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php

$script = <<< JS


 $(function () {

    $('#example1').DataTable( {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": true,
  "searching": false,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": true,
    buttons: [
       'copy', 'excel','csv', 'pdf'
    ]

} );


 });

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with your codings. You can increase the column size in the excel sheet.

Comment: The column shows the values in scientific version, how do i change it to number

Comment: In Excel sheet, Right click on the cell containing scientific number, click `Format Cells`, then change the number cateory `scientific` to `number`